# Regex to get string between curly braces from nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I need to get multiple strings from nginx.conf

```
   geo $whitelist {
       default 1;
       1.1.1.1/32 0;
       2.1.1.1/32 0;
       3.3.3.3/32 0;
   }

   m = re.match('\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}', str)
```

[Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/KgNfpB/1)

But this is not what I need, I just need the content in parentheses after the whitelist

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is this: `\{((?:\s*?.*?)*?)\}`

Parentheses `()` denote capturing groups in regular expressions. `(?:)` can be used to group things without capturing them in a capture group.

In your original regex you have a capture group, but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
 m = re.match(' m = re.match('\{(\s*?.*?)*?\}', str)
```

[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/dp1CtN/1)

My own answer is this, I do not know if there are other answers